# How to hydrate a resource_uri in django-tastypie?

Tags: django, tastypie

I just have a Resource uri, like `'/api/v1/myobjectresource/23/'`, and I need to hydrate it.
It means, I want to instantiate MyObject(pk=23) from its `resource_uri`. How should I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extracted from https://gist.github.com/794424

> def get_resource_uri(self, bundle_or_obj):
>
> ```
> kwargs = {
>     'resource_name': self._meta.resource_name,
> }
> if isinstance(bundle_or_obj, Bundle):
>     kwargs['pk'] = bundle_or_obj.obj.id # pk is referenced in ModelResource
> else:
>     kwargs['pk'] = bundle_or_obj.id
> if self._meta.api_name is not None:
>     kwargs['api_name'] = self._meta.api_name
> return self._build_reverse_url('api_dispatch_detail', kwargs = kwargs)
> ```