# Django API tastypie and FK POST

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm using tastypie and I have created my first resource. But how do I do the following:

username is passed on the URL, on post I would like to 'do stuff' before it is save. does tastypie have a method for this?

```
class CommonMeta:
    authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
    authorization = UserObjectsOnlyAuthorization()



class SMSResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta(CommonMeta):
        queryset = Batch.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'sms'
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get']
```

model:

```
 content = models.TextField(validators=[validate_GSM_characters])
    type = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=TYPES,
                            default="Standard", null=True, blank=True)
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=PRIORITIES,
                                default="Normal", null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=STATUSES,
                              default="Pending", null=True, blank=True)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, help_text="Shows when object was created.")
    schedule = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, help_text="Shows when object was created.")

    #FK
    sender_name = models.ForeignKey(Originator)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Comment: We need your models to be able to see what you're referring to, your question isn't that clear.

Comment: added model updated question :)

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to do. Can you include the Json of what you're trying to send to your server, as well as the thing you're trying to create from a FK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your POST contains the complete information needed to create a User object, it should create automatically. If it doesn't, you can use the `obj_create` method to iterate through the JSON and create the user object manually.

Comment: does does tasty pie have a post method I need to add to override it? i.e. post_data() added to resource class?

Comment: @User7 Out of the box, TastyPie handles POST. If you send a curl request to your API endpoint as a POST, you can test this out yourself.  There's no need for you to write a specific override for POST. When TastyPIE receives a POST against the "list" URL, it will automatically try to create a new object for that resource.

Comment: right, but I want to do stuff before a post like valid a user etc. is this possible?

Comment: hydrate? is this what I need?

Comment: @User7 You could validate the user in either the `obj_create` method or in `hydrate`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603754/how-to-hydrate-a-resource-uri-in-django-tastypie